Failed to connect to the database error: invalid page in block 22 of relation base/12971/2674
I am trying to run in-memory Postgres using pgmock, the connection is getting established but getting this error while running any query.

Failed to connect to the database error: invalid page in block 22 of relation base/12971/2674

code for your reference:
const { Client } = require('pg');
const { PostgresMock } = require('pgmock');
const client = new Client({
    user: "postgres",
    host: "localhost",
    database: "postgres",
    password: "pgmock",
    port: "5432",
});
async function connectToDatabase() {
    try {
        const mock = await PostgresMock.create();
        const connectionString = await mock.listen(5432);
        console.log("connectionString" + connectionString);
        await client.connect();
        console.debug("Connected to the postgres database named: " + "postgres");
        await client.query(`CREATE TABLE Persons (
    PersonID int,
    LastName varchar(255),
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Address varchar(255),
    City varchar(255)
)`);
        console.log("Table created successfully");
    } catch (err) {
        console.error("Failed to connect to the database", err);
        throw err;
    }}
connectToDatabase();

I have tried to refer to the documentation but there is not much detail.

I'd say a corrupted disk, but you say it's an "in memory postgres" so corrupted ram-disk in effect I'd guess.

Is there any problem in pgmock packge, since java in-memory dependencies working fine for me..

File an issue here pgmock issues

The database is corrupted and missing a system index.

@LaurenzAlbe How can I fix this? Any thoughts?

No; this needs an expert who can work on the machine directly. There are no important data in the database, right? Then best forget about it.

@LaurenzAlbe Problem is this package (pgmock)creating a service for postgres in my local which will be used my my code so no need of mocking .I am looking for other npm packages giving the same feature...Mention here if you have any knowledge on this

Just use PostgreSQL itself.

@LaurenzAlbe I am writing unit test cases for my node project by using jest, so i should use in-memory postgres only

With big enough shared buffers and unlogged tables, PostgreSQL will effectively be in memory.
